# warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am new to C programming, I am doing a linked list so that I can find, display,
insert, delete and sort the nodes; however, the compiler giving me these errors:

> main.c:1:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

and I have no clues what are they.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void dump_list (struct data_node *current); 

void dump_node (struct data_node *current);

struct data_node * find_node (struct data_node *p, int elem);    

int delete (struct data_node **p_first, int elem);

struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem, char *newname);

struct data_node {    
    char name [25];    
    int data;    
    struct data_node *next;    
};    

void dump_list (struct data_node *current) {    
    printf("Printing list:\n");

    while (current != NULL) {    
       printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);
           current=current->next;    
    } /* end while */

    printf("\n");   

}; /* end dump_list */    

void dump_node (struct data_node *current) {    
    printf("Printing node: ");

    if (current != NULL)    
        printf("%s: %d\n", current->name, current->data);

}; /* end dump_node */

struct data_node * find_node (struct data_node *p, int elem) {    
    while (p != NULL) {    
        if ( elem == p->data )    
            return p;    
        p=p->next;    
    } /* end while */

    if(p==NULL){
       printf("Node not found\n");
       return p;
    }    
}; /* end find_node */

int delete (struct data_node **p_first, int elem) {    
    int retval = 0;    
    struct data_node *current, *prev;    
    current=*p_first;

    while (current != NULL && elem != current->data ) {    
        prev=current;    
        current=current->next;    
   }

    if (current == NULL) /* element not found */    
        return retval;

    /* current now points to node to delete */    
    if ( current == *p_first ) /* delete 1st node */    
        *p_first = (*p_first)->next;    
    else  /* link previous to next thus skipping over node to delete */    
        prev->next=current->next;

    free(current);

    retval=1;    
    return retval;
}; /* end delete */

struct data_node * insert (struct data_node **p_first, int elem, char *newname) {
    struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;    
    current=*p_first;

    while (current != NULL && elem > current->data) {    
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;

    } /* end while */

    /* current now points to position *before* which we need to insert */    
    new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));    
    new_node->data=elem;
    strcpy(new_node->name, newname);    
    new_node->next=current;

    if ( current == *p_first ) /* insert before 1st element */    
        *p_first=new_node; 
    else                       /* now insert before current */
        prev->next=new_node;    
    /* end if current == *p_first */

    return new_node;

}; /* end insert */


int main (void) {



char key;

int newelem;
char newstring [25];
int removeelem;
int findelem;

struct data_node *first=NULL, *ptr;



printf ("Enter list command (+-flx): ");

scanf (" %c", &key);
int newelem;
char newstring [25];
int removeelem;
int findelem;


switch (key)

   {

       /* tyep +*/

       case '+':


                 printf ("+ detected \n");

                 printf ("Enter key data: \n");

                 scanf ("%D", &newelem);

                 printf ("What string to store? \n");
                 gets(newstring);

                 insert(&first, newelem,newstring);

                 break;

       /* tyep -*/

       case '-':


                 printf ("- detected \n");

                 printf ("Enter key data: \n");

                 scanf ("%D", &removeelem);

                 delete(&first, removeelem);

                 if(delete(&first, removeelem) ==0)

                 printf ("Data not found.  No deletion performed. \n");

                 break;

       /* tyep f*/

       case 'f':


                 printf ("f detected \n");

                 printf ("Enter key data: \n");

                 scanf ("%D", &findelem);

                 while (ptr != NULL)

                 {
                 ptr=find_node(first, findelem);               

                 dump_node(ptr);

                 }

                 printf ("Node not found. \n");

                 break;

       /* tyep l*/

       case 'l':

                 printf ("l detected \n");

                 dump_list(first);

                 break;

       /* tyep x*/

       case 'x':

                 printf ("Goodbye. \n");


                 break;

       /* no default case necessary here */

   }

   return (0);

} /* end main */
```

Comment: Why do you repeat your #includes and your definition of data_node?

Comment: don't pump us your whole code on the web side, but reduce it to a minimal example that reproduces your problem. By doing so you'd probably find the error yourself. Most probably this isn't even the code that produces the error and you have mixed up your files.

Comment: "main.c:1:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive" implies the is something at the end of line 19: maybe `#include <stdlib.h>`.  It could be a whitespace like `'\r'`.  Sometimes this happens from mixing editors.  If needed, delete line 19 and retype it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>





struct data_node {

   char name [25];

   int data;

   struct data_node *next;

   };
```

you have declared struct data_node twice and wrote #include twice.

Comment: my bad, i removed the duplicates but still gives me the same errors

Comment: @user2864813 you defined struct data_node twice

Answer (score 0):

You also need to move variable definitions from the `switch` block and put them at start of `main`.

The lines I am talking about are:

```
int newelem;
char newstring [25];
int removeelem;
int findelem;
```

Comment: i just put them under main and updated the code above, but still giving me errors

Comment: I see that you have copied them twice. At least, that's what I see in the posted code.

Comment: sorry which lines are dups? i have very bad eyes

Comment: Look at the lines after `char key;` and after `scanf (" %c", &key);`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've programmed in C, but I seem to remember that function declarations are not necessary if they are defined before the `int main(void) {}` function. I think you have an error in one of your other functions that is preventing the compiler from finding the `main` function. Try putting them below `main` and see what happens.